# Integration of jenkins with visual studio team services

Tags: git, visual-studio, jenkins, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to integrate jenkins with visual studio team services in order to automate build generation process.

I have followed this blog : https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/integrate/service-hooks/jenkins-and-vso-vs

But i am not able to find git repositories option
[image]

Can anyone please tell me what to do next as git option is not availble?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start please make sure you have the [Git Runtime](https://git-scm.com/) installed. This is mentioned as a requirement here:  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

After you install the Git Runtime you can install the Jenkins Git Plugin by...

Step 1) Go to Manage Jenkins:

[image: Jenkins Home Page]

Step 2) Click on "Manage Plugins"

[image: Manage Jenkins Plugins]

Step 3) Click on "Available", then search for "Git plugin", then click the box for "Git plugin" and click on "Install without restart".

[image: Jenkins Available Plugins]

Step 4) Additional dependencies/updates may get installed but you should see something like this:

[image: Jenkins Git Plugin Installation Success]

Step 5) Start using it in your project.

[image]

I hope this helps.

It also sounds like you may be new to Jenkins. If this is the case I would recommend checking out this quick tutorial on [Jenkins CI](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/jenkins-introduction). You can easily go through it during a free trial period on [Pluralsight.com](https://www.pluralsight.com/)